# Data plot is flipped in PCA

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

#### Background:

Hi, I'm doing a school project with the mnist handwritten digits dataset. The task is to implement PCA. The problem that I am having is when I plot my data in 2 dimensions and compare it to sklearns PCA, my data is flipped on the scatter plot. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code or does sklearn do something differently that causes the data to be flipped? Thanks for any help!

---

#### The Data:

The data is the mnist dataset. It is a numpy array size (400,784) where each row is an image (zero or 1 digit) and the columns are the pixels of a 28x28 image. So the following code produces one of the digits:

```
# visualize images:
# each image size: 28*28, it is reshape to a 784*1 vecter
# eg. 'train_images' is an 400*784 array, each row is a reshaped image.
# use the following code to reshape a vector to a matrix
image = train_images[0]
reshape_image = image.reshape((28, 28))
plt.imshow(reshape_image)
```

[image: One image]

---

#### My PCA Code:

The following is my implementation of the PCA code. The task is to calculate the eigenvectors of PCA and then use the top 100 eigenvectors to reduce the dimensionality to 100. Zeros_and_ones is the original data of size (400,784) containing the digits zeros and ones.

```
# PCA on the 0 and 1 images:
# Centralize the data by subtracting the mean
orig = zeros_and_ones
zeros_and_ones = zeros_and_ones - np.mean(zeros_and_ones)

# Compute covariance matrix 
cov = np.cov(zeros_and_ones.T)
print(cov.shape)

# Compute eigenvectors from covariance matrix 
from numpy import linalg as LA
w, v = LA.eig(cov)
print(v.shape)
v = v.T
```

The output of the following code prints this:

```
(784, 784)
(784, 784)
```

Project the data and reduce to 100 dimensions:

```
# Project the images into the first 100 eigenvectors to reduce the dimensionality to 100
print(zeros_and_ones.shape)
print(v[0:100].T.shape)

# (400, 784) * (784, 100) = (400, 100) -> 400 images, 100 dimensions 
proj100dim = np.dot(zeros_and_ones, v[0:100].T.real)
print(proj100dim.shape)
```

The output of the prints:

```
(400, 784)
(784, 100)
(400, 100)
```

---

#### Plotting the data using my PCA code:

```
# Project the 100 dimension data into 2 dimensions so we can view the 400 points in 2D
plt.scatter(proj100dim[:,0], proj100dim[:,1])
```

[image: My pca plot]

---

#### Plotting the data using sklearn PCA:

Orig is the original zeros and one's np array shape (400,784)

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# reduce to 100 dimensions using sk learn 
pca = PCA(n_components=100)
pca_data = pca.fit_transform(orig)

# plot the first 2 dimensions on a scatter plot
plt.scatter(pca_data[:,0], pca_data[:,1])
```

[image: sklearn PCA]

Comment: Also see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py#L460) for the sklearn's underlying source code for PCA

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thanks for the help!